# Node.js wait until each iteration in for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, asynchronous

I have a for loop

```
for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        console.log("Entered the to for " + i);
        let employee = await this.prolesChecker.getEmployeesFromEmail(options[i]);
        let isOnVacation = await this.prolesChecker.isOnVacation(employee, moment());
    }
```

The two functions "getEmployeesFromEmail and isOnVacation" are connecting to a database and they need some time until result is returned. 
I want the for loop to wait until the result is returned and then go in the next iteration.

As an example the console.log always prints

```
Entered the to for 0
```

It never goes to i = 1

Here is the function

```
 public async deleteEmailsTo(options: any) {
    console.log(options.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        console.log("Entered the to for " + i);
        let employee = await this.prolesChecker.getEmployeesFromEmail(options[i]);
        let isOnVacation = await this.prolesChecker.isOnVacation(employee, moment());
        if ((!employee.EmailReminders && !isOnVacation) || (!employee.EmailReminders && !employee.EmailRemindersForHoliday && isOnVacation)) {
            let index = options.indexOf(options[i], 0);
            if (index > -1) {
                options.splice(index, 1);
                console.log("Removed " + employee.Name + " " + employee.LastName + " from the 'to' list");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: If the for loop in a function? If so, the function has to be `async`

Comment: The loop already *does* wait until the returned promises are fulfilled with the results. If it waits forever, that suggests the returned promises don't resolve properly. Show us the relevant code of `getEmployeesFromEmail` and `isOnVacation`

Comment: @JulianZucker It is, otherwise it would immediately throw a syntax error instead of advancing until the first `console.log`

Comment: @Bergi i didn't noticed that.  Then he should `async` module to executed serially

Comment: @Subburaj No, he shouldn't. Promises with `async`/`await` syntax are far superior to the async.js module.

Comment: Yes the for loop is in a function and the function is "async". I will put the function in edit

Comment: @Bergi But in node.js for loop is executed in parallel, so that he doesn't get the desired result??

Comment: @Subburaj It's not. There's an `await` right in there.

Comment: I edited my question, maybe now is clearer.

Comment: @DavidS What do you get logged for the `options.length`?

Comment: @Bergi i get 2 for the options.length (that is the correct)

Comment: @Bergi I have a general doubt regarding node.js, So in the above example we are making the code to execute synchronously means we are loosing the node.js 's asynchronous nature which is considered that node's prominent feature. So now what's the point is using node.js programming? I searched a lot but i couldn't proper explanation. Any idea? views??

Comment: I might try wrapping the function internals with a try catch and log errors out to your error handler (or console for dev). see if the other functions might be failing silently. Do you have access to the prolesChecker method? could you put some logging in there to see where in that process it is hanging?

Comment: @DLowther i know that the error is in the for loop, because in the first iteration everything is working fine every function, and then it never goes on the second iteration.

Comment: I found the error was in other function "getEmployeesFromEmail" that was doing "splice" on the options array.

Comment: are you certain? the console log in the for loop happens before you call either of the await functions, it would run regardless. You are never hitting the top of your second loop, so the functions that come after that initial log are where your error is happening. add a second log to the bottom of the loop construct odds are it won't fire.

Comment: @Subburaj `await` is just sugar for `then` calls on promises, and maintain their asynchronous properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is actually not about the `async`/`await` syntax, which works fine. It's about the use of `splice` during the iteration! That changes the `.length` of your array, and the next iteration won't happen simply because the loop condition didn't apply any more.

If you absolutely have to mutate the passed array, decrement the `index` counter to account for the change in length:

```
for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    …
    if (…) {
        let index = i; // no point in using `options.indexOf(options[i], 0);`
        // if (index > -1) { always true
        options.splice(index--, 1);
//                     ^^^^^^^
    }
}
```

But it's probably much easier to simply create a new array:

```
let result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    …
    if (!…) {
        result.push(options[i]);
    }
}
return result;
```